# How to support variable number of one-to-many relationships in database

Tags: database, django, postgresql, database-design

I am trying to design a Person database. The requirement is that a Person can have one or more varying number of children, cars, jobs, and homes.

So, currently, the way I have designed this is:

```
Person {
   CharField name
   DateField dob
   CharField city
   ...
   # Some standard base person data
}
```

Since I want to support variable number of associations, I create separate tables with one-to-many relationships. For example, I have

```
Home {
    ForeignKey Person
    CharField home_address
    ...
}

Job {
    ForeignKey Person
    CharField company_nme
    CharField office_address
    ...
}
```

And so on for other fields.

This works fine because I can have as many or as few entries per person.

The downside is that for each Person, I do lookup on 5-6 tables. I am going to need more fields, so the lookups will increase.

Is there a paradigm to efficiently design this kind of scenario?

If it is of interest, I use Django with PostGreSql.

Edit:

The server is mostly making REST API responses off the database. The browser client needs the entire data for one Person at one go (to reduce multiple requests over network). So I will have to do the multiple joins together.

Actually, for my Person table, I really do not need any relational-stuff. Other tables in my DB are heavily relational. The reason I am thinking of this now is because I suspect that the lot of joins will result in slower performance, and changing the design later will be difficult.

I also came across JSONField for PostGreSql and I was wondering whether I should use those to save the "hanging-off" data so that the REST calls do not result in a multitude of JOINS. Since this is design level, I am thinking of the issue now because I am not sure changing this going ahead will be feasible.

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: I don't see the issue, this is the point of relational databases, to separate concepts into different tables so you can have a one-to-many relationship without duplicating data. If you haven't already learned about [joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), that would be the correct way to get all the data you need at once.

Comment: Apart from heavy use of the [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) function for relations you know you're going to use, there is not much more optimisation to be done here. As Adam said, this is the point of relational databases.

Comment: Do you use select_related on your queries? as far as you stick to the correct strategies I see no problem with your code, if indeed you need Job and Home to be a foreignkey then I see no harm with what you have done.
If you start experiencing problems, then it would be a good time to start thinking about cache strategies.

Comment: @knbk that would be select_related for a foreign key.

Comment: @petkostas Yeah, but `prefetch_related` for the reverse relation. I'd guess there would be more queries starting with the `Person`, but good that you mention it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I am not a database expert, but doesn't having multiple JOINs impact performance. select_related also does JOIN. Thanks for pointing prefetch_related. I am not sure what "join in Python" means here though. Eventually in the database this will translate to lot of joins. Will that not impact performance very soon? Or maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Everything 'impacts performance'. Without knowing the project you are working on, it's hard to say if you're selecting and updating data correctly. Basically write a query to perform one task, such as "getUsername" or "getOffices", rather than doing a huge query and pulling back all their data at once, since you might not need it all. Yes joins slow down your query, but don't worry about that at this phase of development. _"The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet."_ — Michael A. Jackson

Comment: Thanks @Adam. I added an edit to the question describing the usage and the reason I am considering this now, than later.

Comment: You suspect joins will slow down your performance, but you haven't tested it. Do the joins, do it in a relational way and then profile it. If you truly care about optimization this early on, then you should test all possible options before making a decision. Realistically, unless you're serving hundreds of requests at a time, and you're joining over 10 tables, it won't be an issue. JSON fields are also a decent idea, except the database will be less relational, since you can't 'relate' your other tables to that JSON data easily.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will take this advice. (as an aside, how can I mark a comment as an accepted answer?)

Answer (score 0):

Your design is correct. The number of tables is a reflection of the complexity (or not) of the application.

The "paradigm to efficiently design this kind of scenario" is the relational model and you are designing in terms of tables because you are working within that paradigm.

Your notions about "the downside" and "lookups" and "efficiency" presume implementation aspects without justification. The DBMS takes your declarations and updates and answers your queries and hides how. Implementation issues do arise, but far from the level of experience and knowledge suggested by your question.

Just make a staightforward design.